# Access Database From Another Computer

Tags: mysql, sqlexception

i want to create multi terminal for floreant post on local area network. so I connect 3 (A, B, C) computers through a switch where computer A acts as a server. On computer A I install xampp and create a new user (user@192.168.100.150) for database access. 192.168.100.150 is the ip address static for computer A. computer B & C can ping computer A through IP Address.

On computer A I managed to setup a database for Floreant Pos without any problems. but on my B / C computer I can not set up the database, the database server address I enter 192.168.100.150 and password for user@192.168.100.150. when testing database connection on computer A from computer B / C I get this error:

> ERROR: 14-May-2018 21:16:18: Connections could not be acquired from the underlyi
> ng database!

here is the complete errors: [connection could not be acquired](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AjfylAw5QZpdnM1qxkWBxeQBmB5JXCux)

how to solve this problem? any advice will be appreciated. i have search all the possible solution in stackoverflo or google but i cant find the one that can solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mysql security using an account user@192.168.100.150 menas it is allowed to connect only from a specific network IP address, maybe Access control need to be set to Allow remote connections from any host for the user or just you want to add it for different IP user@192.168.100.151 assuming computer B is using 192.168.100.151

Comment: i see, thanks a lot @P. Lion, it solve my problem, thanks a lot